# Performance problems with DrRacket's editor

Tags: performance, editor, racket

I am required to use DrRacket for a CS course I am taking and have run into the problem that the editing features of DrRacket are too slow to even be usable.  The REPL window on the bottom works fine for the most part, but I can't write any code for my course.

I am currently running on an intel 2.2GHz x 2 with 5.7GiB RAM and Ubuntu 14.4.  DrRacket it version 5.3.6.

Comment: Fundies 1 any chance?

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ Huh? What do you mean?

Comment: Besides Greg Hendershotts suggestion you can limit the memory use for your program. In the "Racket" menu choose the menu item "Limit Memory..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I don't recall what it was for 5.3.6, newer versions of Racket enable background expansion by default. It might help to disable this? To do so:

1. Open the **Preferences** dialog.
2. Click the **Background expansion** tab.
3. Un-check the first check box, **Enable background expansion**.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, at least, the slowdown appears to be due to memory consumption.  In those cases, saving your work, closing the program, and restarting is likely to help.